# Output of the functions based on nodes

Tags: c++, output, nodes

I am new at coding cpp and I don't understand how we can get the following outputs about the nodes subject? can anyone help?

Thanks in advance :)

The output of the following program is

10 3 22 33

5 7 6

3 22 33

2 4 6

Here is the code:

```
void display(Node *head){

  if(head == NULL)
     cout<<"head is NULL"<<endl;

  for(Node *tmp=head; tmp!=NULL; tmp = tmp->next )
     cout<<" "<<tmp->data;
     cout<<endl;
}

Node *func1(int value1, int value2, int value3){
  Node *head = new Node;
  head->next = new Node;
  head->next->next = new Node;
  head->next->next->next = NULL;
  head->data = value1;
  head->next->data = value2;
  head->next->next->data = value3;
  return head;  
}

void func2(Node *head1, Node *head2, Node *head3){
  head1->next = head3;
  head1->next->data =3;
  head1= head2;
  head1->data = 5;
  head1->next->data = 7;
  head2 = head3;
  head3 = head1;
}

 void func3(Node *head){
    for(; head!= NULL; head = head->next)
        head->data *=2;
}

 int main(){

 Node *head1 = func1(10,20,30);
 Node *head2 = func1(2,4,6);
 Node *head3 = func1(11,22,33);

 func2(head1, head2, head3);
 display(head1);
 display(head2);
 display(head3);

 head1 = func1(1,2,3);
 func3(head1);
 display(head1);
 return 0;
 }
```

**EDIT:**

can anyone explain how can we see the changes in data items although we can't see the changes of local pointers? I assume we shouldn't see any the data changes too since the head pointers are copies of the real ones?

For example we can see head1->data = 5 but the part head2=head1 has no effect. why?

I'm very very confused about that topic please help :(

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you don't understand.  Are you expecting it to output something else?

Comment: in func2 we make head2 =head3 and head2 = head1  but when i apply these equalities i cant get the same result as above

Comment: i think the order of the outputs should be completely different because of these equations

Answer (score 0):

`func2` isn't doing what you think:

```
void func2(Node *head1, Node *head2, Node *head3){
  head1->next = head3;
  head1->next->data =3;
  head1= head2;
  head1->data = 5;
  head1->next->data = 7;
  head2 = head3;  // this has no effect
  head3 = head1;  // this has no effect
}
```

When you say `head2 = head3`, you are only changing the local head2 pointer, you aren't changing the corresponding pointer of the caller.  This is also true for `head3 = head`.

What you may have intended to do is pass the pointers by reference:

```
void func2(Node *&head1, Node *&head2, Node *&head3){...
```

Now the corresponding pointers in caller will be affected by the assignments. If the parameters are not references, then they are just copies of the arguments that were originally passed.

Comment: @cppnewer: I've extended my answer.  See if that is clearer.

Comment: thank youu i understand this part:) but i didnt get the changing data values part  how we can change the values and observe these changes outside the function although we cant see the local pointer changes